# trying to create vkCreateImageView results in exception

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, 2d, vulkan

In my last couple of posts, I have shown that my knowledge of Vulkan is very minuscule.  I have another problem. I cannot use vkCreateImageView without getting an exception.

I tried setting the variables to random values, didn't work.

```
VkImageCreateInfo info {};
info.arrayLayers = 0;
info.extent = VkExtent3D();
info.flags = 0;
info.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
info.initialLayout = VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
info.mipLevels = 1;
info.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;
info.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;
info.samples = VkSampleCountFlagBits::VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_64_BIT;
info.sharingMode = VkSharingMode::VK_SHARING_MODE_END_RANGE;
info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
info.tiling = VkImageTiling::VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR;
info.usage = 1;


auto re = vkCreateImage( _logicalDevice, &info, nullptr, &_img );


VkImageSubresourceRange d {};
d.aspectMask = 1;
d.baseArrayLayer = 0;
d.baseMipLevel = 0;
d.layerCount = 0;
d.levelCount = 0;

VkImageViewCreateInfo createInfo = {  };
createInfo.image = 0;
createInfo.format = VkFormat::VK_FORMAT_A2R10G10B10_UNORM_PACK32;
createInfo.viewType = VkImageViewType::VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
createInfo.subresourceRange = d;


VkResult r = vkCreateImageView( _logicalDevice, &createInfo, nullptr, &_imgView );
```

I expect the output to be VkSuccess, but the actual output is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adhering to the Vulkan specifications. E.g. in the image sub resource, `layerCount` or `levelCount` must either be greater 0 or set to `VK_REMAINING_ARRAY/MIP_LAYERS`.

And in your actual you view you have to pass an actual image handle to `createInfo.image`. Zero is not a valid value.

All of this is noted in the valid usage of the specs, for the image sub resource, see https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkImageSubresourceRange.html.

In Vulkan it's crucial that you check valid usage for everything you pass to the api.